# Referring to properties in a list

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple alarm handler, where I want to have a fixed set of alarms to constantly check if should be either set or cleared.  I have an ObservableCollection property containing the alarm objects.

I would very much like to have the Alarm object contain some form of reference to the property containing the value the alarm should be evaluated against.  This way I can just enumerate through the ObservableCollection and set the AlarmStatus member depending on the evaluation result.  But how can I do this?

From what I can see, using properties byref is not allowed in C#.  I guess using the name and path of the property as a string and then searching for it could be done, but this seems a bit "over the top".

Here is an approximation of the AlarmHandler class:

```
public class AlarmHandler {
    public ObservableCollection<Alarm> AlarmList { get; set; }
    public CancellationTokenSource AlarmEvaluatorCts { get; set; }
    public Controller Controller { get; set; }

    public AlarmHandler(Controller controller) {
        Controller = controller;
        AlarmEvaluatorCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        AlarmList = new ObservableCollection<Alarm>();
        AlarmList.Add(new Alarm(AlarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS, AlarmType.MINOR, ComparisonType.NTEQ, true, null, ref Controller.SerialPortHandler.IsSerialPortOpen));
        AlarmList.Add(new Alarm(AlarmId.x0011_INPUT_VOLTAGE, AlarmType.MAJOR, ComparisonType.GTLT, 100, 200, ref Controller.RovModel.InputVoltage));
        AlarmList.Add(new Alarm(AlarmId.x0012_TEMPERATURE, AlarmType.MAJOR, ComparisonType.LT, 80, null, ref Controller.RovModel.Motor.Temperature));
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AlarmEvaluator(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void AlarmEvaluator() {
        while (!AlarmEvaluatorCts.IsCancellationRequested) {
            foreach (Alarm alarm in AlarmList) {
                // Check each Alarm object if the input value passes or fails given comparison parameters,
                // and set or clear alarm status flag accordingly.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the application starts, it first instantiates various handler classes, and at the end instantiates the AlarmHandler class to monitor values in the other handler classes.

In the constructor I'm first storing the reference to the Controller object (the object managing all the handlers and stuff), then setting up the the CancellationTokenSource for the AlarmEvaluator method, instantiating the ObservableCollection property and adding alarms to it (an alarm for monitoring serial port status, an alarm monitoring that input voltage is within range 100-200 Volts, and an alarm monitoring that the motor temperature is less than 80 degC.  Finally I'm starting the AlarmEvaluator method in a separate thread.  It will run as long as the application is running.

Here is an approximation of the Alarm class:

```
public class Alarm : BindableBase {
    private AlarmStatus _alarmStatus = AlarmStatus.CLEARED;
    public AlarmStatus AlarmStatus {
        get { return _alarmStatus; }
        set {
            SetNotify(ref _alarmStatus, value);
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public AlarmId AlarmId { get; private set; }
    public AlarmType AlarmType { get; private set; }
    public ComparisonType ComparisonType { get; private set; }
    public double LowThreshold { get; private set; }
    public double HighThreshold { get; private set; }
    public double InputValue { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }

    public Alarm(AlarmId alarmId, AlarmType alarmType, ComparisonType comparisonType, double lowThreshold, double highThreshold, ref double inputValue) {
        AlarmId = alarmId;
        AlarmType = alarmType;
        ComparisonType = comparisonType;
        LowThreshold = lowThreshold;
        HighThreshold = highThreshold;
        InputValue = inputValue;
    }
}
```

Note: I know there's a problem with the logic regarding the first alarm being a bool type and the Alarm class not defining a constructor allowing a bool type inputValue.  That's sort of why I'm posting this question, as I'm not sure how to achieve this behavior.  But I'm just giving an example of what type of behavior I'd really *love* to achieve. :-)

Comment: "Now, I would very much like to have the Alarm object contain some form of reference to the property containing the value the alarm should be evaluated against." Maybe I'm alone in this, but I have no clue what you actually want (other than a vague idea that you're hoping to validate data iteratively). Can you supply an example use case (even if pseudo-code)?

Comment: I apologize.  Please see use case added to the first posting.

Comment: I was looking for a code example more than an explanation (but I very much appreciate the effort!). I have already added an answer, which I think will address the core of your problem. I'm having trouble constructing an answer that fits for your specific case (due to not quite understanding it), but I hope my answer helps you. You seem to grasp your own problem well enough that I expect you're capable of implementing my general example (if it is the actual solution of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update 2 - as per your request

I've reread your question many times, and I'm still not quite sure about the specifics of your case. I think you're using defined classes in a way that their name makes sense to you, but not to a reader who's inexperienced in your application.

For example, I'm beginning to infer that your `Alarm` class is actually an object whose main goal would be better described as `ErrorCheck`, which may or may not **cause** an alarm if the error check fails. Is that a correct interpretation?

Regardless, I do think that the crux of the solution rest in this line of code you added:

```
AlarmList.Add(new Alarm(AlarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS, AlarmType.MINOR, ComparisonType.NTEQ, true, null, ref Controller.SerialPortHandler.IsSerialPortOpen));
```

The alarm constructor:

```
new Alarm(AlarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS, AlarmType.MINOR, ComparisonType.NTEQ, true, null, ref Controller.SerialPortHandler.IsSerialPortOpen)
```

Is it correct to infer that you want this `Alarm` object to repeatedly check the value of `x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS`? This is the value you want to read "byref"?

There are two possible answers here. If your `AlarmId` is a reference type, they are functionally equivalent, but if it's a value type, only the second answer applies.

*Note: I am omitting your other constructor variables as they are irrelevant to the example.*
*I am also going to assume (for the sake of example) that your checks will always evaluate to a boolean (whether the underlying value is a boolean, or you are comparing string values, etc.)*

### 1. The better answer

*This works only if `AlarmId` is a reference type!*

In your original example, you passed the **value** of the `x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS` property. Which is wrong, because the value changes over time and your `Alarm` needs to read these updated values.

```
new Alarm(AlarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS);
```

Instead, what you want is to provide the **definition** of how the value should be read in the future (`alarmId => alarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS`), and also the **object** (reference type!) on which you will execute this definition (`AlarmId`):

```
new Alarm(alarmId => alarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS, AlarmId);
```

How would you store this in your `Alarm` class?

```
public class Alarm
{
    private Func<AlarmId, bool> _theErrorCheck { get; set; }
    private AlarmId _theObject { get; set; }

    public Alarm(Func<AlarmId, bool> errorCheck, AlarmId obj)
    {
        this._theErrorCheck = errorCheck;
        this._theObject = obj;
    }

    private bool PerformCheck()
    {
        return _theErrorCheck.Invoke(_theObject);
    }
}
```

Whenever you call `PerformCheck()`, you will read the **current** value (i.e. at the time of calling the method).

However, do note that this only works if `AlarmId` is a reference type. If it is not a reference type, or you create new `AlarmId` objects whenever an update is received, then the above will not work because it keeps referencing the same object over an over.

### 2. The lesser solution

*But the best solution if `AlarmId` is a value type, or you always instantiate new `AlarmId` objects!*

The only difference here is that instead of passing the `AlarmId` in the constructor **once**; you will pass the `AlarmId` in the `PerformCheck()` method **every time you call it**.

```
    new Alarm(alarmId => alarmId.x0010_TELEMETRY_STATUS);
```

And then:

```
public class Alarm
{
    private Func<AlarmId, bool> _theErrorCheck { get; set; }

    public Alarm(Func<AlarmId, bool> errorCheck)
    {
        this._theErrorCheck = errorCheck;
    }

    private bool PerformCheck(AlarmId theObject)
    {
        return _theErrorCheck.Invoke(theObject);
    }
}
```

But as you can see, it's pretty much the same thing.

### Edit again

I also see that your `Alarm` class has thresholds. I infer from this that you have separated the *retrieval* of the value, and the *validation* of the retrieved value.

However, I am actually a proponent of putting these together again.

Let's say you want an alarm that checks if a given value is between 1 and 5. Your (simplified) constructor would then be something like:

```
new Alarm(alarmId => alarmId.GivenValue, 1, 5);
```

However, I would prefer to condense this into a single statement:

```
new Alarm(alarmId => alarmId.GivenValue >= 1 && alarmId.GivenValue <= 5);
```

Functionally, it will do the same thing. But there can be some implementation obstacles with your approach:

- If the properties you read can have different types (string, int, bool), then you will run into problems when trying to define your `Func<T,U>` variable (because the type of `U` can change)
- Your version requires you to create a unique constructor for every type of error check. You're relying on the unique constructor signatures to know what type of error check you want to implement.

Turning it around, my version should have some benefits here:

- It doesn't matter what the property's type is. You're not writing a `Func<T,U>` which *retrieves a property's value* (which can have varying types), but instead you're writing a `Func<T,bool>` which **checks** the retrieved value for correctness (therefore, the output is always a `bool`)
- If you have a wide variety of errorchecking (e.g. `value < max`, `value > min`, `min < value < max`, value is an even number, ...), then it's beneficial to condense this into a single lambda method. That means that your `Alarm` does not change **structurally** based on the method of error checking.

Comment: Thank you very much for a ginormous and informative reply!  However, I'm not quite sure how to use your suggestions to achieve what I want.  Can you please have a look at the extended original posting, where I've added more code?

Comment: @Oystein: I've updated the answer accordingly. I'm still not 100% sure about your case but I do think that I see where the confusion comes from. I've removed my old answer as this update is considerably more specific to your case.

Comment: The AlarmId (number/name) is just for information to the user, as is AlarmType (severity), and will not change once the alarm is defined.  But I think you're right in saying that ErrorCheck is probably a better name though.  Also, you're right in that I'm probably using defined classes in a way that makes more sense to me than other readers.  The point was just to illustrate that I want the Alarm object to point to a property in a different object which will change over time.  Thus I can get the current property value when evaluating the alarm later.

Comment: The Alarm object is not evaluating anything by itself - it's just storing the parameters of the alarm (name, thresholds, (hopefully) a reference to the input value, etc.), and is added to an AlarmList property of type ObservableCollection<Alarm> in the AlarmHandler.  The AlarmEvaluator method in the AlarmHandler is where the evaluation is taking place, when enumerating through all the Alarm objects in AlarmList.

Comment: @Oystein: Oh ok :) But it the `Alarm` contains the "configuration", then just make all properties and method public so your `AlarmEvaluator` can access them as needed. Also, I updated my answer with an edit, which delves into the implementation a bit more. Not guaranteed to be of use to your, but I think it's interesting for you to take a moment to consider the differences in implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your suggestion was a great help to get the alarm handler up and running as I wanted it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to a property, just store the object instance that has that property in your Alarm object and just call it whenever you need to update the AlarmStatus:

```
public AlarmStatusProvider
{
    ...
    string Data { get { return this.data; } }
}

public class Alarm
{
    private readonly AlarmStatusProvider provider;

    public Alarm(AlarmStatusProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
    }

    public void UpdateAlarmStatus()
    {
        // update AlarmStatus based on this.provider.Data
    }

    public AlarmId AlarmId { get; private set; }
    public AlarmType AlarmType { get; private set; }
    public Comparison Comparison { get; private set; }
    public double LowThreshold { get; private set; }
    public double HighThreshold { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public AlarmStatus AlarmStatus { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can update the alarms in you observableCollection by simply enumerating it:

```
foreach(var alarm in observableCollectionOfAlarms) { alarm.Update(); }
```

But I think what I would rather make the `AlarmStatus` property public and update it externally:

```
foreach(var alarm in observableCollectionOfAlarms) 
{ 
    alarm.AlarmStatus = RecalculateStatus(); 
}
```